# Clear a 2d char array

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to ask if there is any fast way(using memset for example) to clear a char table like

```
char mytable[2][10];
```

For example as I know using memset

```
memset(mytable, 0, sizeof(mytable));
```

is used for 1D tables.

Comment: why are you using 'mytable[1][10]' when you can use 'mytable[10]'

Comment: I have it as an example...Let's say that I have 'mytable[2][10]'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're called **arrays,** not "tables".

And the **very same code works** for any array with arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: you answered when I changed the title to 'array'. :) Thanks for your answer

Comment: @dali1985 You're welcome. I suggest you read up on arrays a bit because it's really basic, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written will work for 2-D table as well. Actually it will work for any dimension of the array(assuming you are memset-ing a static array)

Answer (score 0):

**you can use pointer** :

register int i ;

const int max = MAXROW * MAXCOL ;

char *p = &mat[0][0] ;

for (i=0; i < MAXROW * MAXCOL ; i++)

```
*p++ = 'x' ;
```